# How to load a datetime without any separators in polars

Tags: python, datetime, python-polars

I want to load some data from a csv file, which has a column for time. Each time entry is specified as "20170102 0917" - this is year 2017, month 01, day 02, hour 09, minute 17. How can I load this column into polars ?

I am just reading the column as column_1 of dataframe full_df. Then, I am trying  `full_df['column_1'].str.strptime(pl.Datetime,'%Y%M%D %H%M',strict=False)` but it ends up giving null.

Answer (score 2):

You were close:

```py
In [5]: ser.str.to_datetime(format='%Y%m%d %H%M')
Out[5]:
shape: (1,)
Series: '' [datetime[μs]]
[
        2017-01-02 09:17:00
]
```

Comment: `strptime` should work but they didn't include a MWE so who knows.

Comment: oh wait, it's because the m and d need to be lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
df=pl.DataFrame({'a':['20170102 0917']})
df['a'].str.strptime(pl.Datetime, '%Y%m%d %H%M')
```

Note that %m for month and %d for date are lower case.

As a tangent, you should be using expressions in a context, ie...

```
df.with_columns(pl.col('a').str.strptime(pl.Datetime, '%Y%m%d %H%M'))
```

I hope you're not doing

```
df.with_columns(df['a'].str.strptime(pl.Datetime, '%Y%m%d %H%M'))
```